# Split torch tensor/np array using mask into list of tensors

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a 1D tensor of data A. And mask M which is of the same shape as A. The mask M could look like this for example:

```
tensor([0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]
```

Now I want to split my 1D tensor A into a list of 1D tensors according to my mask M. This is easy using loops but this is also "slow". This is why I am looking for a vectorized solution but so far I wasn't able to find a solution.

Here is what I want to do using a for loop:

```
>>> A = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
>>> M = torch.tensor([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3])
>>> [A[M==i] for i in torch.unique(M)]


>>> [tensor([1, 2]), tensor([3, 4, 5]), tensor([6, 7, 8]), tensor([9])]
```

Comment: But not all arrays will have the same size?

Comment: yes this is why I want to split it into a list instead of a 2D tensor

Comment: like i have stated in the post something like this: tensor([0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]

Comment: Probably works but unfortunately I am using torch 1.2 at the moment because of one dependency

Comment: torch.tensor_split does not exist in pytorch1.2 this why I cannot check if it works

Comment: `numpy's` split works by generating a list like `[arr[0:3], arr[3:7], arr[7:12]]`  It iterates as your code does, but uses the more efficient slicing.